# Не могу разобраться с recv

Tags: python

Сервер

```
    def __init__(self):
    self.sock = socket.socket()
    self.sock.bind(('', 9090))
    self.sock.listen(5)
    self.prognoz = pogoda()
    print('Жду соедения...\n')
    self.conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
    self.conn.send('111'.encode('utf-8'))
    print('Соедение с клиентом, адрес ', addr)
    self.pogoda_client()

def getData(self):
    while True:
        data = self.conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
    return data.decode('utf-8')

def sendData(self, text):
    size = sys.getsizeof(text)
    size = str(size)
    size = size.encode('utf-8')
    self.conn.send(size)
    time.sleep(2)
    self.conn.send(text.encode('UTF-8'))
```

Клиент

```
import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))

data = b' '
tmp = b''
while  True:

    tmp = sock.recv(1024)
    size = int(tmp.decode('utf-8'))
    data = sock.recv(size)

    #if data == 'exit':
    #   print ('Close connection')
    #   sys.exit(1)
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
    in_ = input()
    sock.send(in_.encode('utf-8'))
```

[image: server]

[image: client]

Comment: `recv` может вернуть абсолютно любое число байт, как 1, так и все запрошенные 1024 или size — независимо от того, какими кусками отправлял сервер. Вы должны самостоятельно проверять, что вернулось столько, сколько вам надо, и запросить недостающее вторым `recv` или наоборот обрезать лишнее. И только после этого скармливать это всё в `int()` или печатать `data`

Comment: Первым `recv` я передаю вес строки, которую передаю. И печатает именно длину строки, а не саму строку

Comment: Нет такого понятия «первый recv». `recv` возвращает кусок из потока байт, и этот кусок может быть абсолютно любой длины. Может, это будет вес строки, может это будет половина веса строки, а может это будет вес строки и половина самой строки, а может даже вес строки и вся строка целиком — как повезёт. Вы должны сами определить, сколько байт занимает «вес строки», в каком месте заканчивается вес строки и начинается сама строка — `recv` это не делает за вас.

Comment: Даже если этот код каким-то чудом работает, он неправильный по описанной выше причине.

Comment: Идею понял, спасибо :)

Comment: Есть вариант написать обёртку над recv вроде такой: https://pastebin.com/fnFpUbuc Она будет возвращать ровно столько байт, сколько указано в аргументе `cnt` (за исключением случая, если соединение прервано), тогда можно установить длину «веса строки», для примера, 16 байт (дополнив слева нулями, если «вес строки» занимает меньше 16 байт) и с помощью этого метода прочитать ровно эти 16 байт. А потом прочитать ровно `size` байт самой строки с помощью этого же метода. Если так сделать, то, возможно, проблема со скриншота решится сама собой (а может и нет, всё-таки здесь показан не весь код)